# HTML from advertisement not rendered correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

I have many times found CSS written on my screen besides images from Stack OverFlow.

It is associated with the advert from Rackspace

Here is a screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: On what page do you see this?

Comment: I am reading answers on my question.In that page..and it is always with this red image.

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm this bug. Voted.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/r4w12yr.png

Comment: Looks like they tried to use regex to parse their HTML.

Comment: @vivek Experiencing this issue any more? I'd like to mark it status-completed if not.

Comment: yes right now no issues...you can go for it...@stevvve

Answer (score 6):

This looks like an advertiser forgot to put an opening tag in their HTML, and did something like this

```
width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute;" etc etc>100% ssd, 10 GigE blah blah</div>
```

Fairly easy to fix, but not sure how it got past the people in charge of putting the ads on

Comment: Wait. What? Why do the advertisers get to control the HTML?

Comment: @qwertynl they get an iframe, they control its HTML. They have no control over the HTML outside the frame.

Comment: @qwertynl they probably get to control it only to _some extent_. naturally they cannot do simply anything because if an advertising provider's ads became rife with XSS attempts and horrible things, nobody would use that advertising provider and they'd go bankrupt.

Answer (score 2):

@Vivek I can't seem to reproduce this error. Are you (or anyone else who experienced it) still observing this issue?

I checked out [the question you took a screenshot of above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760511/status-bar-backgroundcolor), and even when ads for that advertiser appear I don't have that issue.
[image: ajemplo]

---

Update:
The campaign in question is now paused and the advertiser is in the process of sending us new creative. Will update here when new creative is live.

---

Moar Update:
The advertiser updated their tags and this campaign is now live again. If anyone observes any issues, please let us know.

Comment: yes...I have experienced this thing many times...And when I reload that page it work fine.

Comment: Reproduced now, first try, IE11: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Snvxf.png

Comment: @vivek what browser? Maybe it's IE only problem?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I reproed it a few hours after this question was first posted in Ipad/Safari and Chrome/Windows as well so it definitely wasn't browser specific then.

Comment: @MartinSmith yeah, it appears to be server side. stevvve please see [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213791/152859) (too long for comment) can you send those details to the advertiser and ask them to track it down?

Comment: @ShadowWizard...I am using only firefox

Comment: I just got this on error [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/408614/securely-wipe-an-entire-linux-server-with-itself?rq=1) as well using Firefox 26. Same advertisement as the screenshot in the question.

Comment: @stevvve just in case you missed my prev comment... did you see what I wrote in my answer?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep, currently kicking over some rocks to get to the bottom of the error and getting it fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: @stevvve thanks, but isn't it the advertiser's responsibility?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It is, but given that it's a time of year when many people are not working, it makes more sense for anyone aware of an issue to do whatever possible to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I fear the bug is in their platform though, so better keep an open eye on their new ad too.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to desolate the bug. When it breaks, this is the generated HTML: (the `width="0" height="0"` etc are right after this, outside the tag hence showing bare on the page)

```
<img src="http://data.cmcore.com/imp?tid=17&amp;ci=90378805&amp;vn1=4.1.1&amp;vn2=e4.0&amp;ec=UTF-8&amp;cm_mmc=SMB12Display-_-StackOver-_-Dev-_-PerfLanguage<http://data.cmcore.com/imp?tid=17&amp;ci=90378805&amp;vn1=4.1.1&amp;vn2=e4.0&amp;ec=UT%20F-8&amp;cm_mm" c="SMB12Display-_-StackOver-_-Dev-_-PerfLanguage">
```

The "proper" HTML of this ad is:

```
<img width="0" height="0" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute;" src="http://data.cmcore.com/imp?tid=17&amp;ci=90378805&amp;vn1=4.1.1&amp;vn2=e4.0&amp;ec=UTF-8&amp;cm_mmc=SMB12Display-_-StackOver-_-Dev-_-NewPerfStandard">
```

It appeears to be server side and only happen on first hit, or after hard refresh.

Comment: I like this notion of desolating bugs. "ACME Software! We don't just squash the bugs you report. We *desolate* them! They'll think twice before engaging in error-report uprisings again!"